# How to configure resin4 to save the session to redis

Tags: session, redis, resin

How to configure resin4 to save the session to redis,like tomcat?

```
<web-app id='/dir'>
  <session-config>
     <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
     <session-max>4096</session-max>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing persistence-store type to 'jdbc' and configure data-source with Redis jdbc driver.

```
 <persistent-store type="jdbc">
   <init data-source="jdbc/session"/>
 </persistent-store>
```

Comment: But the Redis jdbc driver is currently in the beta version.